# How to replace QEMU binary with newer version for libvirt live snapshots

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6, snapshot, libvirt

This is my first post, so please be gentle. :)

My CentOS 6.5 box has a QEMU binary that does not support live external snapshots. This is the command I attempt on the virsh CLI, and its output:

```
virsh # snapshot-create-as myvm snapshot1 "snapshot1 test" --disk-only --atomic
error: Operation not supported: live disk snapshot not supported with this QEMU binary
```

**First Question:** Which QEMU binary is this error referring to?

I assumed that the QEMU binary referenced was `/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm`.

**Second Question:** How should the QEMU binary be updated when it isn't available in the operating system's package management system?

I attempted to download the source of a newer version at http://sourceforge.net/projects/kvm/files/qemu-kvm/1.2.0/, compile it, and create a symbolic link that points to the appropriate binary. A listing of the link looks like so:

```
/usr/local/bin # ls -lah /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jan 14 11:20 /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -> /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
```

I then restarted libvirtd, but I'm getting the same error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you run `virsh qemu-monitor-command myvm '{"execute":"query-commands"}'` does the output include "snapshot_blkdev"?

Comment: Also, did you restart your VM after creating the qemu symlink?

Comment: @sciurus Ah, restarting the VM was the issue! The process from the old binary was still running. I also had to run `virsh edit myvm` and change the 'machine' setting from 'rhel6.5.0' to 'pc-1.2', then the VM restarted like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I'll add restarting as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart your VM for it to use the new version of qemu.